# What happens to a familiar if it’s wizard dies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars

High level wizard has a high level familiar. Wizard dies.

What happens to the familiar? Does it still have all the stat boosts and gained abilities? Does it revert to being a normal animal?